# Intel Inspector inspect dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, profiler, intel-inspector

I would like to use Intel Inspector to analyze a DLL. This DLL is for a plug-in application. It goes to a extension folder, is is run from another application, mainApp.exe.

However, in Intel Inspector, when I create a new project from UI, the open tab want an application to profile, and only accepts a file with .exe extension.

I cannot compile the sources in a .exe file. This is because i have no main. I must have two other .exe launched to run the DLL: mainApp.exe, then SDKapp.ex, which I run from the menu bar in mainApp. I tried to compile and concretely I get LNK 2019 error, which does not go away changing the Subsystem to Console.

So, should I stay with other profilers such as AQTime, or is there a way to profile my DLL from Intel Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If DLL should be attached to a process myApp.exe, the target tab application should be myApp.exe.

Inspector will reveal all memory leaks, including those in the DLL that is launched when myApp.exe is running.

See more here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/285260

> Well, attaching Intel Inspector to a process at some arbitrary point
>   in its executionand testing a DLL before the app ends are two very
>   different tasks. Whereas in the former, when Intel Inspector begins
>   its analysis it has no clue regarding what came before, what memory
>   allocations were made, where their boundaries lie, or even how many
>   allocations have been made--forget leak testing and bounds testing on
>   any allocations that occurred before the attach. Picking out a
>   particular DLL (or a set) for testing assumes that the tool was there
>   from the beginning (at least of the DLL run) and gives the tool a
>   chance to capture such allocation data over the duration of DLL
>   activities. And coincidentally, Intel just released Intel Inspector XE
>   2011 for Windows* Update 5 to provide just such a feature:
>
> Enhanced module inclusion/exclusion capability when configuring
>   projects for analysis - for example, you can inspect specific modules
>   and disable inspection of all other modules, or disable inspection of
>   specific modules and inspect all other modules